# Handing Case Class Exceptions and Compiling them

Tags: scala

I am trying to get these two classes to link up. 
PatientMonitorExceptions.scala

```
abstract class PatientMonitorExceptions extends Exception
case class InvalidHeartRate (str:String) extends PatientMonitorExceptions
```

Here is my main.scala that I am trying to compile with the following line:

main.scala

```
   import gasguru.patient.PatientMonitor
   import gasguru.patient.Patient
   import gasguru.patient.exceptions.InvalidHeartRate
   object Main extends App  {

    val p = new Patient("snyder","brad");
    val v = p.vitalSigns
    val pm = new PatientMonitor(p);
    p.vitalSigns.heartRate = 160;
    println("The patient's heart rate is: " +  p.vitalSigns.heartRate     + " bpm");
    try { pm checkHeartRate v.heartRate
    }
    catch {
      case InvalidHeartRate(x) => println(x);
      case _ => println("Something else");
    }
  }
```

I am running: `scala main.scala` to compile this
error: error while loading InvalidHeartRate, Missing dependency 'class InvalidHeartRate', required by ./gasguru/patient/exceptions/InvalidHeartRate.class

What does this error message mean?

Comment: It suggests that your class runtime classpath is different from your compile-time classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `main.scala` references `InvalidHeartRate`, it is referring to the companion object created for your case class `InvalidHeartRate`, and invoking the `unapply` method on it to do the match. The `InvalidHeartRate` object is dependent on the `InvalidHeartRate` case class being in the classpath. The error message occurred because even though the companion object's `.class` file (`InvalidHeartRate$.class`) could be found, the `.class` file for the case class itself is missing (`InvalidHeartRate.class`). I would suggest deleting all your `.class` files and recompiling.